# Prevent method from being called twice in a class that can be called with "with"

Tags: python, function

I'm writing a class that can be used with a `with` statement like so:

```
with Context() as context:
    if context:
        ...
```

The class has an `enter` function that should only be called once and returns a boolean. I want to prevent it from being called twice (eg `with Context().enter() as context`):

```
class Context(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ENTER_HAS_BEEN_CALLED = False

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.enter()

    def __exit__(self):
        self.exit()

    def enter(self):
        """Do things once and only once
        Returns boolean, not self
        """
        if self.ENTER_HAS_BEEN_CALLED: 
            # not sure what to do here, return?
            # call self.exit()?

        self.ENTER_HAS_BEEN_CALLED = True

        # do things that should only be done once
        value = True # or False
        return value

    def exit(self):
        pass
```

Is this the right way to prevent a function from being called twice? I want the return value, and also to allow this code to work:

```
context_manager = Context()
context = context_manager.enter()
if context: ...
context_manager.exit()
```

Comment: The `with` statement is exception safe. Your alternate use is not.

Comment: good point @DanD. It's really only for testing that I want the other use case

Comment: `with Context().enter() as context` will already raise an exception, since `Context().enter()` does not return a context manager. Is that not enough?

Comment: @user2357112 yes, you're absolutely right, that's definitely enough. I hadn't tried it in the `with` yet

Answer (score 2):

You are close, however, you can simply raise an error if the contextmanager has already been called, after setting a flag using a decorator. The code below is written so that both `enter` and `__enter__` can return the separate variables (`True` and `self`) as intended originally and in keeping with the general idea of a contextmanager:

```
def control_manager(f):
   def wrapper(cls):
      if getattr(cls, 'flag'):
        raise Exception("Already expended the context manager")
      setattr(cls, 'flag', True)
      return f(cls)
   return wrapper

class Context:
   def __init__(self):
     self.flag = False
   @control_manager
   def __enter__(self):
     return self
   def __exit__(self, *args):
     pass
   @control_manager
   def enter(self):
     return True
   def exit(self):
     #do something
     pass

with Context() as f:
 v = f.enter()
```

> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 2, in 
> > >         File "", line 4, in wrapper
> > >       Exception: Already expended the context manager

However, it will work on the second test:

```
c = Context()
v = c.enter()
c.exit()
```

However, if you want to use `enter` as the main block for the contextmanager in the class, you can treat it as a `classmethod` with `contextlib.contextmanager`:

```
import contextlib

class Control:
   flag = False
   def __init__(self):
     pass
   def __enter__(self):
     with Control.enter() as f:
       v = f
     return self
   def __exit__(self, *args):
     pass
   @classmethod
   @control_manager
   @contextlib.contextmanager
   def enter(cls):
     yield True


with Control() as f:
  pass
#runs without exception

with Control.enter() as t:
  pass
```

> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "", line 4, in wrapper
> > >       Exception: Already expended the context manager

Answer (score 1):

I like @ehacinom's solution better than @Ajax1234's, because ehacinom's solution keeps the responsibility for the object's integrity within its own class. Ajax1234's solution takes that responsibility to another class, which is generally considered bad practice.

But I would omit the additional `enter` and `exit` methods. These methods may only entice you to use the object outside a `with` block, which is not a good thing. If you really feel the need to use this object outside a `with` block, you probably need to reconsider your design.

ehacinom also forgot the parameters for the `exit` method. So this would be how I'd implement the class:

```
class Context:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__running= False

    def __enter__(self):
        if not self.__running:
            logger.info("Entering Context object")
            # initialize things here
            self.__running= True
        else:
            logger.info("Already entered Context object")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.__running:
            logger.info("Exiting Context object")
            # terminate things here
            self.__running= False
        else:
            logger.info("Already exited Context object")
```